# Importing shapefiles made up of .adf files to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, esri-grid-format, esri-coverage-format, south-africa

I am trying to download this shapefile and get it into a format that ArcGIS Online will accept. The shapefile is primarily made of .adf files.

http://bgis.sanbi.org/SpatialDataset/Detail/416

Comment: "Shapefile" is not a generic term for spatial data; it is a specific file format, involving a set of files with `.shp`, `.shx`, and `.dbf` suffixes.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you see `*.adf` files you are not looking at shapefiles.

Instead you are looking at either:

- vector data in Esri's old Coverage format
- raster data in Esri Grid Raster format

Neither are listed as supported formats at [What can you add to ArcGIS Online?](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-items.htm) so to use them you will need to convert them into a supported format.